# HTML Dynamic Form empty array value

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have some dynamic inputs that are supposed to insert into an array value then passed to my PHP forloop so I can insert into my MYSQL DB.

I am having an issue where my array is coming up empty.
At first, I was getting an error saying invalid object passed to the array. I added

```
if (is_array($faqQuestions) || is_object($faqQuestions)) {
}
```

arround my foreach loop to figure out that is not getting the correct values.

So I know my issue has to be in my form.

So the first visible input is as follows...

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
   <input name="faqQuestions[]" type="name" class="form-control seller input" placeholder="Question" value="<?php echo $question ?>">
   <textarea class="about-textarea" name="faqAnswers[]" rows="3" placeholder="Answer"><?php echo $answer; ?></textarea>
</div>
<input class="add-another-button" type="button" value="Add Another +" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

So the two input names are faqQuestions[] and faqAnswers[].
If the user click adds another, the same form inputs should appear with the same name as an array.

```
        var counter = 1;
        var limit = 5;
        function addInput(divName){
            if (counter == limit)  {
                alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
            }
            else {
                var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                newdiv.innerHTML = "Faq " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input name='faqQuestions[]' type=\"name\" class=\"form-control seller-input\" placeholder=\"Question\"\n" +
                    "                           value=\"<?php echo $question ?>\">\n" +
                    "                    <textarea class=\"about-textarea\" name='faqAnswers[]' rows=\"3\"\n" +
                    "                              placeholder=\"Answer\"><?php echo $answer; ?></textarea>";
                document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

And the PHP that is capturing the array

```
    $faqQuestions = $_POST["faqQuestions"];
    if (is_array($faqQuestions) || is_object($faqQuestions)) {
        foreach ($faqQuestions as $question) {
        //I have tried assigning each variable like $q1 = $question[0]
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to figure out why my array is empty but I just dont see it. 
Hope someone out there can help! Thanks

Comment: `<form> .... </form>` you have form tags right?  Sorry have to ask as I don't see them in the question.

Comment: Also I don't think `<input type="name" >` is a valid HTML5 type but it should default to text.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes!, I only took part the relevant parts of the form to show for example.

Comment: Ok, I've seen it happen believe it or not...  It shouldn't be an object. I would do `var_export($_POST)` or `var_export($_POST["faqQuestions"])`  That should tell you what is going on.  This is an age old adage, "when in doubt print it out"

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks! I was able to fix the issue! Now If I can just call the $_Post[array][1] and assign it to a variable. Whats the point of having a foreach loop?

Comment: The point of a loop is not to access arrays, but to do something repeatedly

Comment: Ahh, so I would use that to display the results in an update form rather than try to get the values from it... Thanks!

Comment: you could use it to as you put it "get the values", its a matter of doing something one time and doing something many times.  A loop is to do something many times, foreach specifically has some additional utility for accessing stuff, but that's not it's purpose.  As with any loop its purpose is to do something many times.  What that "something" is depends on what your trying to do with it, I hope that makes sense.  It's a tool.